# Wifi and wifi hotspot at once

Tags: wireless

I have wifi adapter tp-link tl-wn722n I want to use it to access internet and to share wifi access point at once.

I did it on windows 8:

```
netsh
wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="APname" key="mykey" keyUsage=persistent 
wlan start hostednetwork
```

How can i do this from ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 2):

well check this url as while it may still work, AP-Hotspot is abandoned. That's because there are too many things that depend on the hardware and since it is only tested it on one device(ubuntu 14.04,14.10), that makes the script unreliable for others and for me, pretty much impossible to fix some issues.

How To Set Up A Wireless Hotspot (Access Point Mode) That Supports Android In Ubuntu 
[ap-hotspot](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html)